# Query a nested dictionnary in MongoDB document

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query

I'm trying to learn how to filter out nested dictionaries in the MongoDB database. All documents have the same structure as this example which I will try to get:

[image]

I try to obtain the document thanks to the `Name` which is 'My Burberry - Eau de Parfum':

```
{ "q0.Results": {"Name":"My Burberry - Eau de Parfum"} }
```

But it doesn't give me anything back:

[image]

Comment: you could have tried `{ "q0.Results.Name": "My Burberry - Eau de Parfum" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing:

```
{ "q0.Results": {"Name":"My Burberry - Eau de Parfum"} }
```

says find me documents where `q0.Results` is exactly like this document/subdocument: `{"Name":"My Burberry - Eau de Parfum"}`

In the arrays, you just need dot notation and the following should give you the result:

```
{ "q0.Results.Name": "My Burberry - Eau de Parfum" }
```